# CSS/HTML5: How to adjust div tag height equal to browser window's current height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive

I want the height of my *div* tag exactly equal to the height of the browser's window. So if you resize the browser the  should adjust automatically.
So what should I set my height equal to in CSS.

I have tried

```
.class {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Doesn't work.

em, rem, vh, wh apparently only work with the font.

If I however, hard-code the *body* tag to some amount of pixels, then the percentage works for the children tags but this is not dynamic.

**What I want:** Just as I am viewing this stack page in my browser. I wish when I resize the browser I still get the same amount of page viewership, only resized for the new size (responsive).

Thanks.

Comment: _"em, rem, vh, wh apparently only work with the font"_ - wrong. But `height: 100%;` _only_ works if the parent element has an explicit height set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make div 100% height of browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window)

Answer (score 3):

You want to add `vh` so something like this.

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.container{
  background:grey;
  height:100vh;
}
```

and HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello from the other side</h1>
</div>
```

and here is an [example](https://codepen.io/codearts/pen/Mowdgm).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

to set a height reference for the DIV (any DIV is a child of another element, a DIV without another container is a child of `body`, which is a child of `html`)

Answer (score 0):

Your divs parent is the body. `height:100%` will go as high as the parent. So you need to do this.

```
html,body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by jquery on simple way.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var heights = window.innerHeight;
    $(".class ").style.height = heights + "px";
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add VH height to a div and completely agree with @Nofel.

But it will will for mozilla and chrome. It will not work for Safari or IE.

Add vh property resize the window.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a function to resize the container on window resize.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   Content
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
   height: 100vh;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function resize_container() {
   var height = $(window).height(),
       container = $('.container');

   container.css('height', height);
}

$(window).resize(resize_container);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

You can try `height :100vh` to achieve this. Check below snippet:

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.windowHeight{
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="windowHeight">
  
</div>
```

**Solution 2**

Another way to do this by jQuery. Check below snippet:

```js
$('.windowHeight').css('height', $(window).height());
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
.windowHeight{
  background:#000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="windowHeight"></div>
```